# accessing EnvDTE80 members without type casting

Tags: c#, envdte

I am trying to access the Output Window and ErrorList member of ToolWindows of an EnvDTE.DTE object.  It seems that these members exist in EnvDTE80.DTE2 only.  Is there a way for me to access them without type casting back to DTE2 type?

Answer (score 1):

EnvDTE.Window.Object returns the inner object of the toolwindow. You can use code similar to this, that gets the toolbox:

```
Dim objWindow As EnvDTE.Window
Dim objToolBox As EnvDTE.ToolBox

objWindow = dte.Windows.Item(EnvDTE.Constants.vsext_wk_Toolbox)
objToolBox = CType(objWindow.Object, EnvDTE.ToolBox)
```

See [HOWTO: Get the programmable inner object of a toolwindow](http://www.mztools.com/articles/2006/MZ2006015.aspx)